# How to limit what users can type into a form(Must have @ in field)

Tags: php, html, forms, character, limit

I'm trying to stop a little bit of spam from my form. It's an email list and just takes any text in the box and submits it into my database. Is there a way that I can make it so it checks that the user has added @ in the field?

```
echo '<style type="text/css">';
include 'style.css';
echo '</style>';
if( $_POST )
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","flickey_emails","");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("flickey_emailsubscribe", $con);

    $users_email = $_POST['email'];

    $users_email = htmlspecialchars($users_email);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `flickey_emailsubscribe`.`emails` (`id`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$users_email');";

    mysql_query($query);

    echo "<h2>Thanks for joining the email list!</h2>";

    mysql_close($con);
```

HTML

```
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
Email: <input type='text' name='email' id='email' /><input type='submit' value='Submit' />  
</form>
```

Comment: Put your improved or original code into the question by editing the original question. Not on the comment of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to check if the submitted for has an @ in it, you can use indexOf():

```
var form_text = "random text";
if(form_text.indexOf("@") == -1) {
  //@ was not found, show message, error, etc.
} else {
  //submit form
}
```

Comment: you would need to show your code for me to help with that. you can just use my code onsubmit of the form, and return false if @ is not found

Comment: sorry about that I accidentally submited my comment my code is added into my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use regex for such scenarios.Tyr this

```
`'/^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/'`
```

You can strict user for `@`.Even this can be use for verification of complete email adress format

Here is the testing script

```
$string = "first.last@domain.co.uk";
if (preg_match(
`'/^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/'`,
$string)) {
echo "example successful.";
}>
```

You can also use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for this

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "Valid email address.";
} else {
  echo "Invalid email address.";
}
```